# Can Scala method that returns a trait returns method with the same type as trait?

Tags: scala, interface, traits

I'm trying to write something that looks like this:

```scala
trait interface {
   getA(a:_): trA 
}

trait trA extends (x => y)
```

and the trait is implemented like:

```
object obX extends interface {
   override def getA(a:_): x => y = X => ???
}
```

However, I get error

```
Overriding type a => x => y does not conform to base type a => trA
```

Even though `trA` takes in `x => y`. Is there a way to go around this? is my only option to modify trait interface like:

```scala
 trait interface {
   getA(a:_): x => y
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd recommend that you read a bit more about inheritance. Also maybe provide some concrete code so that we understand your goal in the end. Here `trA` doesn't bring any value for instance.

Answer (score 1):

> Even though `trA` takes in `x => y`.

This is false. A `trA` is a `x => y` but the opposite is *not* true: `x => y` is *not* a `trA`. A `trA` cannot be built from a `x => y`.

Your defining your `obX` with a wider return type than your `interface` allows.

Answer (score 0):

For example your code would compile if you could make `trA` not extend `x => y` but be it

```
type trA = x => y
```

Otherwise you can introduce a type

```
trait interface {
  type Out >: trA
  def getA(a: _): Out
}

object obX extends interface {
  type Out = x => y
  override def getA(a: _): x => y = X => ???
}
```